# negetive width in bit field '<anonymous>' while running 'make'

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, make, sysfs

Thank you for reading this question.

I was trying to compile a kernel module that works with `sysfs`, and while executing `make` I ended up with this error. Can somebody please help me understand what this error means?

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common/include/linux/build_bug.h:29:45: error: negative width in bit-field ‘<anonymous>’
 #define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:(-!!(e)); }))
```

followed by

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common/include/linux/kernel.h:1051:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO’
   BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO((perms) & 2) +     \
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common/include/linux/sysfs.h:103:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS’
    .mode = VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS(_mode) },  \
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/bkkarthik/Workspace/tasks/task09/helloworld.c:76:45: note: in expansion of macro ‘__ATTR’
 static struct kobj_attribute id_attribute = __ATTR(id, 0666, id_show, id_store);
```

I am relatively new to Linux kernel programming, I am not aware of what information you need to assess this situation. Please feel free to ask for further information if needed. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This specific error isn’t particularly important, it’s a “trick” used to break the build if a given value is determined to be zero. To understand why the build is failing, you need to look at the next error message, which should include

> note: in expansion of macro ‘BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO’

followed by the expression which caused the error.

In your case, the build is failing because you’re specifying a world-writable mode, 0666; [you should set at most 0664](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.2/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L1020).